# What is the English expression for "rafting to the upstream, swimming to the edge"

Tags: expressions, proverbs

What is the English expression for the state that someone has to be "sick" beforehand, then at the end achieving the best result?

In my native language, it's said:

> Rafting to the upstream areas (of water)[having sickness beforehand because of hard efforts], swimming to the edge (of the river bank)[achieving the best result at the end].

Comment: I don' understand how rafting upstream equates to sickness. And what is "the edge of water"?

Comment: Hmmm...sorry, I should've make it clearer. Please give me time. It's not always easy to convey the real message in English, as it is classified as a proverb here.

Answer (score 4):

"No pain, no glory." - I think this is a relevant expression.

"No pain, no gain." - This, too, is almost the same. - you'd gain something (result; desired effect) after the 'pain' (either physical pain, or some other things that may be 'sacrificed')

(I also remember this related line: 'No guts, no glory.")